How to delete one line and the line above in Linux?
I have a script which automatically generates an output like this for MySQL:
ALTER TABLE TESTE3 
  ADD COLUMN nome2 VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL;

--
-- Create table `TESTE10`
--
CREATE TABLE TESTE10 (
  ID INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  NOME VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'J',
  nome2 VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL
);

--
-- Drop column `col2` from table `hihi`
--
ALTER TABLE hihi 
  DROP COLUMN col2;

I need to make sure not to drop anything in database, only add.
I need to remove the:
ALTER TABLE hihi 
  DROP COLUMN col2;

sed -i '/drop/Id' file_name_here would remove only the line DROP COLUMN col2. But I need to remove the line above (ALTER TABLE hihi) as well.

There are multiple ways, but in the end, what if it outputs ALTER + ADD + DROP? or ALTER + DROP + ADD as seen in examples there: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/#examples ?

Any drop ie: dro table, drop column, drop index, drop constraints etc

My question wasn't formulated in a precise way. If there's a DROP with an ALTER before, fine remove both. But if there's also an ADD to this ALTER statement, then there can be ALTER possibly either just before as in the current example (if ADD is later) or also a few lines before it (if ADD is between). ALTER must then not be removed. And what of MODIFY (which also loses previous information) etc. This requires to understand the SQL statements.

"I have a script"... then it seems like it should be fairly easy to modify that script.

The script is the dbforge tool. I didn't find a option to remove any drop.

Using any awk and tac:
$ tac file | awk '$1=="DROP"{c=2} !(c&&c--)' | tac
ALTER TABLE TESTE3
  ADD COLUMN nome2 VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL;

--
-- Create table `TESTE10`
--
CREATE TABLE TESTE10 (
  ID INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  NOME VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'J',
  nome2 VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL
);

--
-- Drop column `col2` from table `hihi`
--

See printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern for details on what that c&&c-- is doing and similar idioms.
or if you wanted to delete the comment above that block too then you could set c to 5 (print the blank line) or 6 (delete the blank line), or you could do this to delete from DROP to a blank line inclusive:
$ tac file | awk '$1=="DROP"{f=1} !f{print} !NF{f=0}' | tac
ALTER TABLE TESTE3
  ADD COLUMN nome2 VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL;

--
-- Create table `TESTE10`
--
CREATE TABLE TESTE10 (
  ID INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  NOME VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'J',
  nome2 VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL
);


Seems to work fine. But how to use it as case insensitive?

change $1=="DROP" to toupper($1)=="DROP".

I'll maybe extend this to address the question as it has been layed out, but to address the actual issue at hand: table_options in ALTER TABLE statements are completely optional in MySQL:
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    [alter_option [, alter_option] ...]
    [partition_options]

So if your script is formatted exactly like that (one ALTER TABLE statement followed by a single DROP), you may just replace the DROP statement with a semicolon:
sed -i 's/^ *DROP.*/;/' <input.sql

user@server ~/[REDACTED] (git)-[REDACTED] % sed 's/^ *DROP.*/;/' <input.sql
ALTER TABLE TESTE3 
  ADD COLUMN nome2 VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL;

--
-- Create table `TESTE10`
--
CREATE TABLE TESTE10 (
  ID INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  NOME VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'J',
  nome2 VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL
);

--
-- Drop column `col2` from table `hihi`
--
ALTER TABLE hihi 
;

But it's your responsibility to make sure the script always follows that exact format. Otherwise, as mentioned in the comments, you should probably edit the script the generates the statements, or run a parser on the the output (both are better solutions than this one).

You are right. I didn't know we can issue alter table xxx; without any argument. This help as well.

@Astora Yeah but again, make sure this pattern always apply. If it doesn't and it's easy enough I may try and put toghtether a solution using a parser if needed (never got my hands dirty with that, but I guess it shouldn't be too hard).

You could use pcregrep, or rather pcre2grep these days' -Multiline mode:
pcre2grep -vMi '^\h*alter table[^;]*\sdrop\s[^;]*;' file.sql

To also remove the preceding comments:
pcre2grep -vMi '(^--.*\n)*^\h*alter table[^;]*\sdrop\s[^;]*;' file.sql

